# Heroku logs won't stream with -t or --tail

Tags: logging, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

When I use `heroku open` to get my rails 4 app running and then `heroku logs -t or --tail`, I get an initial list of output in the terminal, but as I use the app no additional output shows up. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's currently a disruption of service with logging:

- Logging service disruption: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/631

That's your problem, unfortunately